# how to open a message box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

i m writing the code:

```
string query = "Select * from AdminLogin where username='" + name + 
               "' and password='" +   password + "'";

DataSet ds = BusinessLogic.returnDataSet(query);
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (dr[0].ToString() == name && dr[1].ToString() == password)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
      //Here I want to write the code that will open a message box 
      //that will tell to user that username and password does not match.
     }
}
```

Comment: Define "message box"? This looks like a website, so do you want a JavaScript `alert()`, text in a `<div>` element, or what?

Comment: but i don know how to call a java script using C#.

Comment: Well you haven't actually asked how to call JavaScript yet anyway...

Comment: Sidenote: Beware of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: try the code given in my answer...

Comment: @Heinzi No SO question with SQL Injection vulnerabilities is complete without a bobby tables link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By message box I'm assuming you mean a javascript alert. I'm not a big fan of posting back with javascript functions. I think its messy, and that javascript should only be used when dealing with client-side actions.

I would actually recommend to use a placeholder and a literal control for this. You could have the following in your webform:

```
<asp:placeholder id="phLoginFailed" runat="server" visible="false">
     <div class="loginfailed">
        Login failed
     </div>
</asp:placeholder>
```

This placeholder could be styled like a popup, or displayed within your page using CSS.

Then change your C# to:

```
else
{
    phLoginFailed.Visible = true;
}
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning, your SQL query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [parameterised queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

And you should encrypt passwords when storing them in the database for security purposes.

Comment: And you shouldn't be storing plain text passwords. Hash them first & compare the hashed values

Comment: @SimonHalsey You've downvoted me for that?

Comment: didn't downvote you. just adding to your very good point about SQL injection. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @SimonHalsey Sorry, I assumed you -1 because I got a downvote at the same time. I've added your point regarding password encryption :)

Comment: @Ankur I need more information than that. What is not working? Are you getting an error

Comment: @Ankur And I'll be impressed if you've managed to parametise your queries, style your login failure and improve your password security in the last 6 minutes!

Comment: ya thanks...but when i am using placeholder and i have visible it then it is not showing error message on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as it sounds. Basically, you have two options:

- Send some JavaScript to the client (for example, using [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)) which calls the JavaScript `alert(...);` method.
- Alternatively, use an ASP.NET component that "looks like" a popup. One example is the [ModalPopup component](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) in the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit.

Comment: can u explain it more...i am not getting what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

just write this line where you want o show message

```
this.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(),"key", "alert('Wrong username or password')",true);
```

**Edited code**

```
 if (dr[0].ToString() == name && dr[1].ToString() == password)
     {
       Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
     }
     else
     {
         this.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(),"key", "alert('Wrong username or password')",true);

       //Here I want to write the code that will open a message box
        //that will tell to user that username and password does not match.
      }
```

Comment: can u tell me what should i write in key?

Comment: @Ankur -any string value you can wirte there ..

Comment: @Ankur - is that work for you ???????

Comment: i have write so many code or logic there but none of output is working there..i don't know why it is going with me...

Comment: and of course i will mark the answer when i get the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(),"key", "alert('Wrong username or password')", true);
```

or if it is used outside page scope
then

```
        Page page = (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page);
        if (page!=null)
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "key", "alert('Wrong username or password')", true);
        }
```